# parse a string to find a number greater than a certain length

Tags: c#

I have a string which is essentially a filename.
Our annoying end users decided that they want to somewhere within the filename put our product code if they feel like it. 
Now the only way that I can think of getting this is to look for a number within a string where the number length is greater than 4. An example is below but i'm unsure how to check whether a string contains a number with a length greater than 4 or not.

```
73767 Carex Wipes Clipstrip Pack - Strawberry Laces.xlsm
```

Comment: Try using regex to find all numbers used in your filename and compare match length with desired one.

Comment: If it's always at the start, then it makes it a little easier, but, generally speaking, you just need to loop through the characters of the string, checking each char if it's >= '0' and <= '9' and incrementing a counter until you hit a non-numeric char or the end of the string. If it's greater than 4, you've got your product code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a simple *regular expression*:

```
  String source = "73767 Carex Wipes Clipstrip Pack - Strawberry Laces.xlsm";

  // "{5,}" pattern - 5 or more digits == "length is greater than 4" 
  Boolean result = Regex.IsMatch(source, "[0-9]{5,}");
```

To *obtain* these numbers you can use *Linq*:

```
  var numbers = Regex.Matches(source, "[0-9]{5,}")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => int.Parse(match.Value));

  // 73767
  Console.Write(String.Join(", ", numbers));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a combination of string methods and LINQ:

```
string fn = "73767 Carex Wipes Clipstrip Pack - Strawberry Laces.xlsm";
var numbers = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn).Split()
    .Where(s => s.Length > 4)
    .Select(s => s.TryGetInt32())
    .Where(nullableInt => nullableInt.HasValue)
    .Select(nullableInt => nullableInt.Value);
int firstNumber = numbers.DefaultIfEmpty(-1).First();
```

Used this handy extension method to get a `int?` from a string:

```
public static int? TryGetInt32(this string item)
{
    int i;
    bool success = int.TryParse(item, out i);
    return success ? (int?)i : (int?)null;
}
```

Comment: I like this! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex as suggested.

```
[0-9]{4,}
```

This will find 4 or more numbers together.

```
public static string[] PotentialProductCodes(string input)
{
    Regex codesSplit = new Regex("[0-9]{4,}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    List<string> list = new List<string>();

    foreach (Match match in codesSplit.Matches(input))
    {        
        list.Add(match.Value);
    }

    return list.ToArray<string>();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        PotentialProductCodes("73767 Carex Wipes Clipstrip Pack - Strawberry Laces.xlsm"));
}
```

Comment: Why are you trimming a comma from something that only matches numeric values?